# Correlation dropping NAs R

Tags: r

I have a kind of weird dataset, where I need to restructure the responses of a participant, then correlate the values. I do this, however it keeps producing NAs. Basically, individuals responded to 22 questions, I now need to take these values and correlate them together. Therefore, first I need restructure the data, for each individual, then calculate the correlation:

```
for (i in 1:length(my_data$RId)){

  cor1<- c(my_data$A1[i], my_data$A2[i], my_data$A3[i], my_data$A4[i], my_data$A5[i],
           my_data$A6[i], my_data$A7[i], my_data$A8[i], my_data$A9[i], my_data$A10[i],
           my_data$A11[i])

  cor2<- c(my_data$I1[i], my_data$I2[i], my_data$I3[i],my_data$I4[i], my_data$I5[i],
           my_data$I6[i], my_data$I7[i], my_data$I8[i], my_data$I9[i], 
           my_data$I10[i], my_data$I11[i])

  my_data$cor[i] <- cor(cor1, cor2)
}
```

Naturally, if there is an NA, then I would like to keep the case and ignore the NA, but I am having problems getting that to work.

Comment: you can use cor(cor1,cor2,use="p") this uses all pairwise observations.. But you got to be aware this means different n (sample size for different rows)

Comment: Sorry what does this mean? But you got to be aware this means different n (sample size for different rows), my brain is somewhat melted.

Comment: Kindly paste the output of `dput(head(my_data))`.

Comment: I meant it might not be correlation of 11 complete observations. Might be 10 or 9 etc.. if there's NAs

Comment: but yeah it's a really weird data structure you have there

Comment: I agree, it is weird. Once the observations are dropped in sequence it does not matter much for N of 10 or 9. Another issue is that when the scores are the same - for instance, everyone puts 11 for all 22 items - it puts NA. When I thought that would be a perfect correlation...

Comment: @JDG sorry, there's about 300 variables * >3000 rows, so dput is clunky.

Comment: Thats because the standard deviation = 0. You gotta throw those out or flag it